Omnetpp skipping a huge amount of sim time, making the simulation stops
The event "ProsumerNetExtraLarge.schedulerModule (MosaikSchedulerModule, id=3)", after proceeding right with its time for a long period of the simulation, suddenly skips a huge amount of time making the whole simulation to just stop! I use cosima: https://github.com/OFFIS-DAI/cosima/tree/master
Event #393411  t=3.654  0% completed (0% total) ProsumerNetExtraLarge.schedulerModule (MosaikSchedulerModule, id=3)

... then basically right after (I expect it to be around 3.7, but..):
2024-09-18 20:04:31:974196  | DEBUG   | OMNeT++: MosaikSchedulerModule: received until event. sim time is: 999999.999

** Event #395303 t=999999.999 10% completed (10% total) ProsumerNetExtraLarge.schedulerModule (MosaikSchedulerModule, id=3)

The code responsible of the "received until event" is here:https://github.com/OFFIS-DAI/cosima/blob/master/cosima_omnetpp_project/modules/CosimaSchedulerModule.cc
The code responsible for the socket handling is instead here: https://github.com/OFFIS-DAI/cosima/blob/master/cosima_omnetpp_project/modules/AgentAppTcp.cc
Other details:
As seen in the trace above, at a certain point the MosaikSchedulerModule receives an until event in handleMessage, but at that moment the omnet simTime() call already returns 999999 (the maxAdvance value, in fact I set until=that value in the mosaik world). The problem is that I can't trace this simTime() jump from whataver value (can be anything, is apparently "non deterministic") to the until value. So even if I manage to manually block the until event, obviously the simTime() will now return 999999 for every other call, eventually leading to the end of the simulation. So it would be amazing even just to know how to trace up this simulation time sudden change, because my only guess for now is that the omnet kernel changes it to 999999 in its library, and that's why I can't understand where it happens (I swear I tried printing simTime everywhere and I can't find a point in which it skips to that giant value before that handleMessage call). Is there some subtle interaction that I'm losing? Is there a way to prevent this from happen and just continue the simulation? Thank you really a lot!
The only thing that seems to be consistently present in all the runs, just before the failure, is the presence of a slightly higher number of "socket data arrived" messages, but everything I printed there seems to be okay. I also noted that the number of present messages is increasing (for omnet docs seems to be a possible segfault, but I never touched .cc codes so there shouldn't be a missed delete on my side).
I checked and there are a lot of events present (even too much, and in fact I thought it could be an overload due to mem leaks, but I excluded this option because it can stops in every moment (1s, 20s, 100s, 150s, whataver) so how can the simulator handle 150s once and not handle 1s?). I now append my new discoveries:
In this omnet function, at HEY1 the time is still OK, then in HEY3 it suddenly becomes 999999:
void cSimulation::executeEvent(cEvent *event)
{
#ifndef NDEBUG
    checkActive();
#endif
    setContextType(CTX_EVENT);

    // increment event count
    currentEventNumber++;

    std::cout << "HEY1: sim time: " << simTime() << std::endl;

    // advance simulation time
    currentSimtime = event->getArrivalTime();

    std::cout << "HEY3: sim time: " << simTime() << std::endl;

In the getArrivalTime() function in cevent.h it becomes coherently 999999 in that time, so later on I'll continue inspecting cevent functions to understand what is happening, but maybe this gives you a better idea.
Thanks!

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

You're right, sorry, I never explicitly mentioned that I was using cosima coupling (omnet + mosaik). I edited

I eventually added other discovered details
